# Translate user inputted text before storing in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I have a site where users can input comments. I want to be able to translate those comments into another language before storing them in a database.

For example, the comments inputted could be in Chinese, and I would want to translate these comments into English before storing them.

Most translation APIs only translate entire Web pages.

please guide me with any idea!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Unicode and Check range of the Value, if out of English, convert them using ajax web service...; you need to create a web service that converts passed string(may be suing google) for more guidance paste some original work..

Comment: @Vld ya its "using", my bad TYPO.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Google Translation API specifically does work for any text, not just entire Web pages. Based on their API [docs](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR-API-KEY&source=zh-CN&target=en&callback=translateText&q=YOUR-SOURCE-TEXT
```

should translate a phrase from Chinese to English.

Comment: Many thanks for this, but I should have mentioned that I am looking to use one of the free services, at least at this stage. Bing has lower fees than Google, Yandex is now charging, and with Baidu it is difficult to find the code, except in node.js